# Capturing camera framebuffer on iPhone 3G (not S)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, framebuffer

I've downloaded a free application from App Store (very nice application for instance) called ReadTheQRCode and it dont asks you to take the picture to decode the QRCode, my point is, is the application using the framebuffer of the camera on iPhone 3G or it is taking several pictures at a given time, ommiting the iris animation, the edit step and decoding it? Can anyone with more experience take a look at this App and give an opinion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is `-[UIImagePickerController takePicture]` (as of 3.1) and `UIGetScreenImage()`. Although the latter is undocumented, Apple allows apps using it into the store (see [this thread on the Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/149553#149553)).